# Formatting in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, formatting, decimal, percentage

I am getting the content of a JSON file into the variable $variable and filtering the $variable on a condition as in the code below and holding the filtered data in $logs. The output of echo $logs is as below.

```
0.842093077,
0.792955,
0.8910225,
0.8724875,
0.852885333,
0.774708,
0.987243333,
0.87078,
0.9565,
0.839393333
```

My question is how do i convert each of these decimal values to a percentage like 84.20 %, 79.20% and so on, so that when the mail goes out with the Percentage Utilisation field as a percentage value and not a decimal value?

DESIRED SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
Workspace Name         : A NAME
Workspace Allowance    : 100
Workspace Usage        : 79.2955
Workspace Size Free    : 20.7
**Percentage Utilization : 79.29**
Predicted Usage        : 86.05585477
```

PRESENT OUTPUT

```
Workspace Name         : A NAME
Workspace Allowance    : 100
Workspace Usage        : 79.2955
Workspace Size Free    : 20.7
*Percentage Utilization : 0.792955*
Predicted Usage        : 86.05585477
```

```
# Convert the CSV file into its JSON equivalent
    import-csv "Workspacesize.csv" | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "output.json" -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    
    
    # Import email settings from config file
    
    [xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "Settings.xml"
    #Write-Output $ConfigFile
    
    $emailTo = @(abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com)
    # Create email content
    $smtpsettings = @{
    
        From = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailFrom
        Subject = "TEST EMAIL"
        SmtpServer = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.SMTPServer
        }
    
   
    
    [String]$messagebody = ""
    $variable=Get-Content -raw "output.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
    $logs=$variable | Where-Object { [double]$_.'Percentage Utilization' -gt 0.75}
    echo $logs
    
    
    } 
    foreach ($log in $logs )
    {
        $messagebody = $messagebody + $log + "`r`n"
    }
    
    $messagebody  = $logs | Out-String
    $messagebody = '<pre>' + $messagebody + '</pre>'
     
    
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #  Script
    #-------------------------------------------------
    
    try
    {
     Send-MailMessage @smtpsettings -To $emailTo  -Body $messagebody -BodyAsHtml -Encoding utf8 -verbose -ErrorAction Stop
     }
    
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
    
    # MOVE THE JSON & CSV FILE TO AN ARCHIVED LOCATION
    
    Move-Item -Path $Jsonfile -Destination C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\Desktop -Force
    Move-Item -Path $Csvfile -Destination C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\Desktop -Force
    
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #  The End
    #-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Change `$messagebody  = $logs | Out-String` to `$messagebody = $logs | Select-Object *, @{n = 'Percentage Utilization'; e = { [Math]::Round(($_.'Percentage Utilization' * 100), 2) } } -ExcludeProperty 'Percentage Utilization' | Out-String`

Comment: And also remove the loop above: `foreach ($log in $logs ){...}` because there you create the string `$messagebody` and imediately after that you overwrite it completely.

Comment: Why would you first import your CSV, convert it to json, save it as json file and then later read that data back in into a variable `$variable` ? Seems to me you already had that data if you started off with `$variable = Import-Csv -Path 'Workspacesize.csv'`

Comment: @Daniel - with your code, the Percentage utilisation field is coming blank.

Comment: Could be that the value is of type string.  You can try this `$messagebody = $logs | Select-Object *, @{n = 'Percentage Utilization'; e = { [Math]::Round(([float]$_.'Percentage Utilization' * 100), 2) } } -ExcludeProperty 'Percentage Utilization' | Out-String`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you can simplify the code by using the data from the CSV file and only if you really also need that in JSON format, convert that data and save it at the end of the script.

```
$CsvFile = 'C:\Somewhere\Workspacesize.csv'

$data = Import-Csv -Path $CsvFile
$logs = $data | Where-Object { [double]$_.'Percentage Utilization' -gt 0.75 }
# update the 'Percentage Utilization' property on each item
foreach ($item in $logs) {
    $item.'Percentage Utilization' = [Math]::Round(([double]$item.'Percentage Utilization' * 100), 2)
}
# format the mesage body as monospaced formatted list output
$messagebody = '<pre>{0}</pre>' -f ($logs | Format-List | Out-String)

# Import email settings from config file
[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "Settings.xml"

# BTW. it is better to use:
# $ConfigFile = ([System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()).Load('X:\Path\To\Settings.xml')
# because that way you'll get the encoding right. 
# You need to load it using the absolute Full path and filename

# Create email splat hashtable
$smtpsettings = @{
    To         = 'abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com'
    From       = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.MailFrom
    Subject    = "TEST EMAIL"
    SmtpServer = $ConfigFile.Settings.EmailSettings.SMTPServer
}
# try to send the email
try {
    Send-MailMessage @smtpsettings -Body $messagebody -BodyAsHtml -Encoding utf8 -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}

# move the csv file to an archived location
Move-Item -Path $Csvfile -Destination 'C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\Desktop' -Force

# if you really also need a json file from the data retrieved from the Csv, convert and save it here:
$data | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\Desktop\output.json'
```

Comment: IT DOES NOT WORK. THE PERCENTAGE UTILISATION IS COMING AS 0. Workspace Name         : IAP IPP DW - PRD
Workspace Allowance    : 130
Workspace Usage        : 109.4721
Workspace Size Free    : 20.5
Percentage Utilization : 0
Predicted Usage        : 146.0246408

Comment: @SiddharthaDas Please try again. I have fixed my typo.

Comment: Can you please mark out he change or the edit you have done?

Comment: @SiddharthaDas, click on the edited link below the code to see the diff

Comment: @SiddharthaDas I had mistakenly put `$_.'Percentage Utilization'` in the foreach loop where it should be `$item.'Percentage Utilization'`

Answer (score 1):

Quick example with format specifier p for percentage, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings.  The inputs are [double] type.

```
0.842093077,
0.792955,
0.8910225,
0.8724875,
0.852885333,
0.774708,
0.987243333,
0.87078,
0.9565,
0.839393333 | % tostring p

84.21%
79.30%
89.10%
87.25%
85.29%
77.47%
98.72%
87.08%
95.65%
83.94%
```